# Topological matroids?

Tags: general-topology, matroids

Are topological matroids something that has been studied?

I would like to construct and study mathematical models of an abstract world consisting of a finite number of particles in a finite number of states of motion and think that the "nearby" from topology and the independence from matroids together could be a good start.

The idea is to derive a space-time like background from structures on a finite set of states of motion. I want to examine possibilities to study sets of moving elements (i.e. elements that would be interpreted as moving in a geometrical frame) represented as "states" in a world without a continuum. As an abstraction, a sort of game with structures...

With a topological matroid I mean a triplet $(X,\mathcal I,\tau)$, where $(X,\tau)$ is a finite topological space, $(X,\mathcal I)$ is a matroid and also eventually some interaction between the structures.

All tips and ideas is welcome.

Comment: As far as I know, no. There aren't many interesting topologies on a finite set to begin with; since matroid are used to represent vector configurations, any representation of the matroid will factor through the quotient where two indistinguishable points are identified. In the end, it reduces to discrete matroids, I think.

Comment: @Najib: OK, but neither the matroid nor the space need to be interesting as such, only more interesting than just trivial.

Comment: This doesn't really contribute anything, but some people call flats of a matroid 'closed sets' and their set complements (aka cyclic sets) 'open sets', suggesting an analogy with finite topological spaces somehow. The circuit axioms are kind of similar to the (open) base axioms, likewise the hyperplane axioms are kind of similar to the closed base axioms.  (Also the 'closure' operator takes any set to the smallest 'closed set', i.e. flat, containing it.) They aren't the same though, but I am still trying to figure out exactly _how_ different they are, hence why this comment does not add much.